# Admob does not shows on real device

Tags: android, admob

I had integrated to view ads programmatically , It seem to be working on emulator , but not on my LG G3 device , I recheck my entire Code , Not getting where I am Getting Wrong ,..

Here Is my Ads Activity Page code :

```
public class TerrorKill extends Activity {

    Surface view;
    WakeLock WL;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //full screen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //TODO: --------------------------------------------------------------------------change advert unit id
        AdView ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "ca-app-pub-1114663329734183/8892144958");//enter advert id here
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        //layout
        view = new Surface(this, this);

        LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        ad.setLayoutParams(params1);

        layout.addView(view);
        layout.addView(ad);
        setContentView(layout);

        //TODO: ad-------------------------------------------------------------------------add testing devices if you wish
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        /*request.addTestDevice("275D94C2B5B93B3C4014933E75F92565");///nexus7//////testing
        request.addTestDevice("91608B19766D984A3F929C31EC6AB947"); /////////////////testing//////////////////remove///////////
        request.addTestDevice("6316D285813B01C56412DAF4D3D80B40"); ///test htc sensesion xl
        request.addTestDevice("8C416F4CAF490509A1DA82E62168AE08");//asus transformer
*/      ad.loadAd(request);


        //wake-lock
        PowerManager PM = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        WL = PM.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "Graphics");
        WL.acquire();

        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int rotation = display.getRotation();
        if (rotation == 0)
            view.default_lanscape = true;
        if (rotation == 180)
            view.default_lanscape = true;
        if (rotation == 90)
            view.default_lanscape = false;
        if (rotation == 270)
            view.default_lanscape = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            view.back();
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        view.pause();
        WL.release();

    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        view.resume();
        WL.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        WL.release();

    }

}
```

Here is My android Manifesto

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.techom.TerrorKill"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.techom.terror.TerrorKill"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.techom.terror.EnterHiscore"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to check more if you can attach logcat report with your code. there is a posibility that your ad is going out of view, attach logcat it will be easy to know whether you are getting ads or not.

Comment: it takes 24hours + to be fed adverts - depends on your amount of users. Check your LogCat it will say something like "no advert to serve"

Comment: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.ads.adinfo                                                         Unable to open content URL: content://com.google.android.gms.ads.adinfo/any.gif?zx=kfps5r5xe5pn

Answer (score -1):

Things to check:

1. Internet connection on your device
2. XML of your ad layout

Comment: Everything is proper from my end

Comment: @SujitSoni This was my sincere answer. Every developer is at a different stage. What may seem very obvious to you may not to me. I tried to genuinely help you. Please don't down vote my answer. This is very discouraging.

Comment: I had not voted you down , ..I just said what it seem to me.